# Calling functions in Android after a period of time

Tags: android

I would like to call some functions at an interval of time. How could I use a Timer in Android to achieve this?

This is my piece of code

```
for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {imb_items[j].startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);}
```

I want to run an animation for each of these imageViews, which I keep in imb_items[], but I don't want the images to overlap, so I have to start the animations at different periods of time.

thank you!

Comment: Why dont you just do it on a different thread, and then use Thread.sleep('<milli sec>'); ??

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this.. call your function from run().

Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    yourfunction();

                }

            });
        }
    }, 0, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
for(int j=0; j<i;j++) {
   translateAnim[j].setStartOffset(5000*j);
   imb_items[j].startAnimation(translateAnim[j]);
}
```